# Replace values using Key defined with inline variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to understand the usage of keys and can't get my example to work.

Starting with this XML:

```
<items>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
</items>
```

I want to get this output XML:

```
<items>
    <item>PURPLE</item>
    <item>BLACK</item>
    <item>PINK</item>
</items>
```

I defined the mapping directly in a variable in the XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="mappings">
      <mapping orig="Blue" repla="PURPLE"/>
      <mapping orig="Green" repla="BLACK"/>
      <mapping orig="Orange" repla="PINK"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:key name="mappingsKey" match="$mappings/mapping" use="@orig"/>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('mappingsKey',.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know I'm missing the instruction to tell which is the replacement value, but don't know how to define it.

Example available here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHp/1

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$mappings` variable is in a different document than the processed XML. You need to point the `key()` function to there. And you also need to select the `repla` attribute:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('mappingsKey', ., $mappings)/@repla"/>
```

Referencing the variable in the `match` pattern of the `xsl:key` element is meaningless.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHp/2